# Efficiently generate all vector partitions

Tags: code-golf, restricted-memory

A vector partition is splitting a vector up a series of vectors such that their sum is the original. Here are a couple partitions:

```
[3, 1, 2] = [3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2] = [0, 0, 1] + [0, 0, 1] + [0, 1, 0] + [1, 0, 0] + [2, 0, 0]
[3, 1, 2] = [1, 1, 2] + [2, 0, 0]
```

Here vector addition is done element-wise. A valid partition does not contain any vectors with negative integers, or the all-zero vector.

Now the challenge is to write a program or function that generates all possible vector partitions given a target vector. This may sound relatively easy...

#### ...but there is a twist. If the input vector has size L, and the biggest partition it generates has M elements, you may not use more than O(L*M) memory.

You may assume that an integer uses O(1) memory.
This means that you must output the partitions as you generate them. **On top of that, you must only output each partition exactly once.** For example, these are the same partition:

```
[3, 1, 2] = [3, 0, 2] + [0, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 2] = [0, 1, 0] + [3, 0, 2]
```

If you were to output both your answer is invalid.

---

All partitions for `[3, 2]`:

```
[3, 2]
[0, 1] + [3, 1]
[0, 1] + [0, 1] + [3, 0]
[0, 1] + [0, 1] + [1, 0] + [2, 0]
[0, 1] + [0, 1] + [1, 0] + [1, 0] + [1, 0]
[0, 1] + [1, 0] + [2, 1]
[0, 1] + [1, 0] + [1, 0] + [1, 1]
[0, 1] + [1, 1] + [2, 0]
[0, 2] + [3, 0]
[0, 2] + [1, 0] + [2, 0]
[0, 2] + [1, 0] + [1, 0] + [1, 0]
[1, 0] + [2, 2]
[1, 0] + [1, 0] + [1, 2]
[1, 0] + [1, 1] + [1, 1]
[1, 1] + [2, 1]
[1, 2] + [2, 0]
```

To test your answer, run it on `[3, 2, 5, 2]`. It should generate 17939 partitions, all of which sum to `[3, 2, 5, 2]`, and that are all unique (you can test for uniqueness by first sorting each partition lexicographically).

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 289 bytes

Simple brute force algorithm. Treats entire list as a number in base `max(input)+1` (`b`), and checks each "number" in the range `[0, b**(L*M))` to see if it:

1. Sums to the correct amount
2. Is in alphabetical order (ensures uniqueness)

If the list matches these criteria, the program outputs it with all the all-zero vectors stripped.

#### Memory usage

The largest data structure I use in this program is a doubly-nested list, an list length `M` containing liss length `L` to give `O(L*M)` memory.

For my other data structures, I have 3 global ints `O(3)`, 1 list length `L` (`O(L)`), 1 array length `M` (`O(M)`), and a copy of the largest array when outputting (`O(L*M)`).

In total, this gives me a memory usage of `O(2*L*M + L + M + 3)` which simplifies to `O(L*M)`, fufilling the criteria.

#### Time complexity

Being a brute force algorithm, this algorithm is extremely slow. For the while loop to quit, the final int in the array needs to be `b-1`. The loop needs to run `b**(L*M)` times before that happens.

In addition, each time the list runs, it needs to check both conditions, and print the list in a worst case, using `L*M+L+M` iterations. This simplifies to give an overall `O(L*M * b**(L*M))`. I tried to test my program on `[3, 2, 5, 2]`, but gave up after 45 minutes.

#### Golfed program

```
v=input()
L=len(v)
M=sum(v)
b=max(v)
R=range
t=[L*[0]for i in R(M)]
def A(l,i):
 if i<L*M-1and~-b<l[i/L][i%L]:A(l,i+1)
 l[i/L][i%L]=-~l[i/L][i%L]%-~b
while t[-1][-1]<b:
 if v==[sum(q[i]for q in t)for i in R(L)]and all(`t[i]`>=`t[i+1]`for i in R(M-1)):print[x for x in t if[0]*L!=x]
 A(t,0)
```

I might be able to golf this a bit more, especially the increment part. Ungolfed code coming.

Comment: Definitely not the efficiency I was hoping for when I posted this question, but I guess it _technically_ solves the problem :)